# Is this multi onChange event validate

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple functions that need to fire on the onChange event will this work?

I cannot combine the functions.

```
 onChange="avgFloatPipe(), ReserveFloatingPipe()"
```

Thanks!

Comment: This won't work, because you're assigning a string to an event. Neither the function you wish to invoke will do so. Instead use another with which you can call the other two.

Comment: Unless they mean to make it the onchange attribute of the DOM element in which case it should work fine;

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were assigning it in JavaScript not as an inline html attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on doing things inline that syntax should be fine. You could also terminate each function call with a semicolon.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXevRy

```js
function test1() {
  alert(1);
}
function test2() {
  alert(2);
}
```

```html
<input onchange="test1(), test2();" /><br />
or separating the statements<br />
<input onchange="test1(); test2();" />
```

You could also wrap the functions with a third function and call them both

```js
function test1() {
  alert(1);
}
function test2() {
  alert(2);
}
function test3() {
  test1();
  test2();
}
```

```html
<input onchange="test3()" />
```

A third option is to bind the event using javascript. One way to do this is by using an anonymous function.

```js
function test1() {
  alert(1);
}
function test2() {
  alert(2);
}

document.getElementById("example").onchange = (function () {
  test1();
  test2();
});
```

```html
<input id="example" />
```

Comment: First I would to say THANK YOU for the in-depth coverage on the topic, However I'm still having trouble I have got a codpen example where I'm trying use your suggestions. I would like your feedback please thanks!      http://codepen.io/coryk/pen/Kzbqwo?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

`onChange="avgFloatPipe(); ReserveFloatingPipe();"` if you insist on doing it inline and not making a third function that calls the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Just separate the functions with a semi colon:

```
onChange="avgFloatPipe(); ReserveFloatingPipe()"
```